# split a string with comma and colon

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a string like as shown below:

`var String = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx:some string without comma,xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx:some string,with comma,xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx:some string,xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx:some string without comma,xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx:some string , with comma,xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx:String,with comma"`

Where `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx` represents an alphanumeric generated Id and after the colon is a string related to that Id.The string can be a string with comma or without comma.What I wanted was that I wanted to split the string such that I get an array with ID:its corresponding string , just like shown below.

`["xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx:some string without comma","xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx:some string,with comma","xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx:some string","xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx:some string without comma",
"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx:some string , with comma","xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx:String,with comma"]`

**HOW I ACCOMPLISHED THIS**

I used the javascript split function where i split the string by comma followed by 36 characters (for ID) and colon.

```
String.split(/,(?=.{36}:)/);
```

PS: I apologize as previously I was not able to ask the question in the correct manner.Hope this time people understand it.

Comment: please add a valid result.

Comment: *is it possible using javascript?* **Yes**. Can you share what have you tried?

Comment: @Rajesh i tried using ".split(/:|,/)" ..but not getting it right

Comment: Then please share it in question

Comment: Use `s.match(/\b\w{6}:(?:(?!\b\w{6}:).)*/g)` or `s.split(/,(?=\b\w{6}:)/)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , inspired from your solution i used `split(/,(?=.{36}:)/)` where 36 is the length of my Id followed by colon.

Comment: So, what are the actual requirements? Your question is still unclear. Please update it for the question to be reopened and an appropriate answer could be given. Also, if your ID consists of alphanumeric/`_` chars, you shoud replace `.` with `\w`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) by comma and a look ahead for numbers and colon.

```js
var x = "123456:a,b,c,435213:r,567876:e,363464:t,y,u";
    array = x.split(/,(?=\d+:)/);

console.log(array);
```

For alphanumeric values

```js
var x = "1A3456:a,b,c,43Y213:r,567W76:e,363x64:t,y,u";
    array = x.split(/,(?=[a-z0-9]+:)/i);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: your answer is correct but how to detect for alphanumeric instead of number?

Comment: what is the regex for "last occurence of comma after a colon" and split it using last comma.I found the last occurence of comma using "(?=[^,]*$)" but how to use it here?

Comment: it does not work this way. you have to look what is coming next, not if it is the last.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [.split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp). I used the "$" as a split sign instead of "," because i thought you would like to keep them.

```js
var values = "123456:a,b,c$435213:r$567876:e$363464:t,y,u".split("$");
var x = values[0];

console.log(values)
```